# Verificar Objeto dentro de um Array usando indexOf()

Tags: javascript

Eu estava resolvendo alguns desafios de um curso de JavaScript que eu estou fazendo, e me deparei com um pequeno problema:

Tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

```
var numberObjects = [ 
   {number: 1}, 
   {number: 2}, 
   {number: 3}, 
   {number: 4}, 
   {number: 5}, 
   {number: 6}, 
   {number: 7}, 
   {number: 8}, 
   {number: 9}, 
   {number: 10} 
];
```

E eu preciso verificar se existe o objeto `{number: 2}` dentro desse array, utilizando o método `indexOf()` e retornar uma mensagem no console se for `true` ou `false`, então eu fiz da seguinte forma utilizando o operador ternário:

```
console.log( numberObjects.indexOf( { number: 2 } ) > -1 ? 'Existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects!' : 'Não existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects :(' );
```

O meu problema é que mesmo existindo o objeto `{ number: 2 }` dentro do meu array, o retorno do `indexOf()` continua sendo `-1`, que significa que ele não está encontrando esse objeto dentro do meu array, alguém saberia me informar o pq disso acontecer?

Também tentei fazer atribuindo o retorno do `indexOf()` a uma variável, porém, sem sucesso.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para usar [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) você precisaria testar se é o mesmo objeto. Note que, **só porque um objeto tem as mesmas chaves e os mesmos valores, não quer dizer que sejam o mesmo objeto**. Portanto:

```
let obj_1 = {number: 1};
let obj_2 = {number: 1};

console.log(obj_1 === obj_2); // false
console.log(obj_1 == obj_2);  // false
```

Para resolver seu problema você deve guardar uma referência aos objetos e utilizá-la no [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ou usar o método [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) para fazer o mesmo porém com uma função de testes.

Exemplo com [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
let num_1 = {number: 1},
    num_2 = {number: 2},
    num_3 = {number: 3},
    num_4 = {number: 4},
    num_5 = {number: 5};
  
let objetos = [num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5];

console.log(objetos.indexOf(num_3));  // 2
```

Exemplo usando [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var objetos = [ 
   {number: 1}, 
   {number: 2}, 
   {number: 3}, 
   {number: 4}, 
   {number: 5}
];

function find_obj(obj) {
    return obj['number'] === 3;
}

console.log(objetos.findIndex(find_obj)); // 2
```

---

Também vale lembrar que, se você não se interessa pelo índice onde foi encontrado o objeto, mas só quer saber se ele existe no array o método [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) faz isso pra você.

```js
let num_1 = {number: 1},
    num_2 = {number: 2},
    num_3 = {number: 3},
    num_4 = {number: 4},
    num_5 = {number: 5};
  
let objetos = [num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5];

console.log(objetos.includes(num_3)); // true
```

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, excelente resposta! Mas o exercício pede que eu verifique utilizando `indexOf()` esse array em específico, pois essa declaração de array da maneira que está é a resolução de um outro exercício, por isso não poderia mexer na estrutura.

Comment: Minha dúvida mesmo é o pq de `indexOf()` retornar apenas -1, se o objeto existe no meu array, e ele deveria retornar a posição que ele se encontra, correto?

Comment: Se você verificar a documentação do método `indexOf` verá que ele usa comparação restrita (===)... E como eu expliquei na minha resposta, mesmo que dois objetos tenham as mesmas chaves e valores, eles são objetos distintos em memória. Esse é o motivo, e se você quiser evitá-lo você terá que guardar referências para os objetos originais como mostrei.

Comment: A única referência para os objetos no seu código são a do próprio array, ou seja, para funcionar você deveria fazer `objetos.indexOf(objetos[2])`.. e isso não faz nenhum sentido. Em resumo, ou a pergunta pede algo impossível ou você não entendeu muito bem a questão ou faltam informações para dar uma resposta correta.

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando indexOf mas com ajuda de map. Mas para o value do teu objeto, e não o objeto. Neste caso irá retornar 1, o valor do indice {number:**2**}.

```
numberObjects.map((e) => { return e.number; }).indexOf(2);
```

Comment: Ótima solução Ernesto! Desta maneira não preciso desmontar o array como o colega propôs na outra resposta, e ainda consigo utilizar o `indexOf()`. Muito obrigado a todos por ajudarem! :D

Comment: Vale lembrar que nessa resposta você está percorrendo todo o array antigo, depois criando um novo e só depois procurando pelo valor que você quer. Funcionou para o AP, porém tenham cuidado em usar esta técnica com array grandes demais.

Answer (score 3):

Bom porque essa sua função esta errada!

**Segundo a documentação**

> O método indexOf() retorna o primeiro indice o qual tem o elemento encontrado no array, ou -1 if nao estiver presente.

Faça o teste colocando numberObjects.indexOf( { number: 20 } ), vai dar a mesma resposta ou seja não existe { number : 20 } como valor do array numberObjects.

Que tal usar esta função?

```
function verificar(arr, procurar) {
    var chave = procurar[0];
    var valor = procurar[1];
    return !!arr.filter(function (el) {
        return el[chave] == valor;
    }).length;
}
```

arr é o array:

```
[ 
   {number: 1}, 
   {number: 2}, 
   {number: 3}, 
   {number: 4}, 
   {number: 5}, 
   {number: 6}, 
   {number: 7}, 
   {number: 8}, 
   {number: 9}, 
   {number: 10} 
]
```

e procurar seria o objeto: {number: 1}

Comment: Obrigado Julio! Mas o exercício que estou fazendo pede claramente para utilizar o método `indexOf()`, então não poderia utilizar essa função. :(

Comment: E a função não está errada, em um outro exemplo que fiz aqui o retorno foi correto, segue:
`var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; console.log( arr.indexOf( 3 ) ); // vai retornar o índice do item '3' no array, que no caso é '2'`

Comment: sim, eu digo o ternario

Comment: qual é o erro no ternário?

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma seria convertendo a array em string com `JSON.stringify()` e verificando com `.indexOf()` se possui o objeto em forma de string:

```js
var numberObjects = [ 
   {number: 1}, 
   {number: 2}, 
   {number: 3}, 
   {number: 4}, 
   {number: 5}, 
   {number: 6}, 
   {number: 7}, 
   {number: 8}, 
   {number: 9}, 
   {number: 10}
];

var tem = JSON.stringify(numberObjects).indexOf('{"number":2}');

console.log(~tem ? 'Existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects!' : 'Não existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects :(');
```

Como os objetos estão no formato `chave + valor numérico`, ao converter em string o resultado será a chave entres aspas e o valor numérico logo após os dois pontos:

```
[{"number":1},{"number":2},{"number":3},{"number":4},{"number":5},{"number":6},{"number":7},{"number":8},{"number":9},{"number":10}]
```

Então basta verificar se a string `{"number":2}` existe com `.indexOf()`.

Ao atribuir o `.indexOf()` à variável `tem`, adicionando antes dessa variável o sinal de `~`, irá retornar ou `0` (se não existir, ou seja `false`) ou qualquer número (positivo ou negativo) indicando que existe.

Agora um exemplo que o objeto não existe:

```js
var numberObjects = [ 
   {number: 1}, 
   {number: 99}, 
   {number: 3}, 
   {number: 4}, 
   {number: 5}, 
   {number: 6}, 
   {number: 7}, 
   {number: 8}, 
   {number: 9}, 
   {number: 10}, 
   {number: 22} 
];

var tem = JSON.stringify(numberObjects).indexOf('{"number":2}');

console.log(~tem ? 'Existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects!' : 'Não existe um objeto { number: 2 } em numberObjects :(');
```